# problem on "turtle_tf: Missing resource catkin"

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, this is my error. any body help me plz? :)

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ **rosdep install turtle_tf rviz**

**ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
turtle_tf: Missing resource catkin**

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/mohsen/fuerte_workspace

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share

ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55522/problem-on-%22turtle_tf:-missing-resource-catkin%22/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-18**:
What do you get for `rosdep db | grep catkin`?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-18**:
@Mohsen Hk Btw, I have a feeling that `turtle_tf` might not require to be `rosdep install` although the tutorial says to do so. Can you skip that part and see what happens?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-18**:
That's probably true. Should still work, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin` isn't installed in your machine.

Install it with necessary ROS distro http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin I haven't tried on `fuerte` but try:

```
% sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-catkin
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2016-01-19**:
I am getting same error with

```
roslisp: Missing resource geneus
```

How to solve this?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-01-19**:
@Ameer Hamza Khan Please open a new question. Comment section is not designed for new questions (and it doesn't get as much attention as you want).

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2016-01-20**:
@130s I have opened already opened a new question here http://answers.ros.org/question/224521/roslisp-missing-resource-geneus/